# Shell Script to Parse Date

Tags: bash, shell, date, sed, osx-yosemite

I am using a shell script to process a csv file with data in the following format:

yyyy-mm-dd, value

Each line has a different date and a different value.

I would like to parse each line into the following new format:

yyyy, weeknum, yyyy-mm-dd, value

Where yyyy is the 4-digit year from the date on that line, and weeknum is the week number for that day, month, and year.

I've worked out using the date command to get the weeknum, where I hard-coded the date to 2016-02-01 as an example:

```
echo $(date -j -f '%Y-%m-%d' '2016-02-01' '+%V')
```

But I'm just not sure how to incorporate this date command into something like sed where I can dynamically and globally insert the yyyy and weeknum values into each line based on the actual date value from that line in the file.

Any suggestions for how to proceed would be greatly appreciated!

Sharon

Comment: Can you provide some sample input, along with the expected output you're aiming for, so that we can run a test and be confident that they're the results you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might do:

```
$ uname -sr
Darwin 15.4.0
$ cat inp
2016-01-01, 5
2016-01-09, 15
2016-02-01, 3.14
$ while IFS=", " read d v; do date -j -f '%Y-%m-%d' "$d" "+%Y, %V, %F, $v"; done < inp
2016, 53, 2016-01-01, 5
2016, 01, 2016-01-09, 15
2016, 05, 2016-02-01, 3.14
```

This pops everything into the format for the `date` command, avoiding the need for subshells or temporary variables.

Note the selection of quotes. While format strings are generally considered static, and usually placed in single quotes, if we want to include the variable `$v` in the format, we must use double quotes instead, allowing the variable expansion to take place. Note that if for some reason your input data in the CSV are "dirty", you could break your processing easily, as this provides no input checking besides `date`'s ability to parse the first field.

---

**UPDATE**

If you were to install GNU awk (gawk) on your system using [Macports](https://www.macports.org/) or [Brew](http://brew.sh/), [etc](http://rudix.org/packages/gawk.html), then the following would likely perform better:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=", "} {split($1,a,"-"); print a[1],strftime("%V",mktime(gensub(/-/," ","g",$1) " 00 00 00")),$1,$2}' inp
```

I wrote this as a one-liner, but I'll break the in points for easier explanation.

- `BEGIN { OFS=FS=", " }` - at the start of the script, defines a field separator.
- `{` - the main part of this awk script has no "condition", so will be executed for every line of input.
- `split($1,a,"-")` - split the first field into the array `a[]`, separated by hyphens.
- `print a[1],` - print output, starting with the year,
- `strftime("%V",` - followed by a time format for the week-of-year,
- `mktime(gensub(/-/," ","g",$1) " 00 00 00"))` - generated from a time parsed in mktime's "datespec" format,
- `,$1,$2}` - followed by the other two fields.

I haven't developed any performance metrics, but I'm certain the self-contained gawk option would run significantly faster than the bash-based option which spawns a `date` command for each line of input.

Comment: @l'L'l - there were no backslashes in the input data described by the OP.

Comment: @l'L'I - the data in the file is very clean.  I don't have to worry about any exception processing.

Comment: @ghoti - your solution works very well...except...I failed to mention a very important detail.  Namely, the data file is huge, and the processing is taking quite a long time.  The file is 620,000 rows, so maybe my choice of the date command wasn't the right approach?  Do you have any other ideas for how to handle this?

Comment: Well, not in bash in OSX without extra tools, no. Bash has no internal date mangling functions, it's just a shell. It's likely not the `date` command that's slow, but rather the effort required to run a new `date` command for every line of input. You could probably do something more efficient in perl or python or even in C using strptime and strftime, but that would be totally out of scope for this question. :-)

Comment: @ghoti - yes, i'll look into using another language then.  I will still mark your first response as an answer, though, because it did work.  Thx!

Comment: @SharonG - I've added a `gawk` option which would certainly perform better, and included some links that you might use to get `gawk` installed on your Mac if it isn't already there.